# Kubuntu: Web browser download 'Show in folder' opens in Visual Studio Code instead of Dophin

Tags: dolphin, visual-studio-code, brave

Since installing Visual Studio Code, when I download a file using a web browser (Brave in this situation), the option 'Show in folder' opens Visual Studio Code instead of the expected (and default) file manager Dolphin.

Here's the option I mean:

[image]

**How do I change this back?**

I've looked in Kubuntu's Default Applications, VS Code and Brave's settings and am at a loss!

Thanks for your help  ;o)

Answer (score 5):

**Found it!**

Even though it was last in the list of `inode > directory` file associations, removing it fixes the problem!

System Settings > File Associations > inode > directory

[image]

Comment: Confirm, this works. Weird that Visual Studio Code gets called even though it was at the bottom of this list.

Comment: My hero, this BS just appeared out of nowhere and removing everything but what I want (dolphin) fixed it right up.